# Ionic React Scss style not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The below code is working, but if i rename to styles.module.scss and import it , then stlye is not getting applied, any suggestions please

```
    import classes from './styles.module.css'; 
    const MyContainer: React.FC =(props) =>{   
    return(
              <IonCard>
                <IonCardContent class={classes.test}>
                   <div className="test">
                   </div>    
                </IonCardContent>
              </IonCard>
    );
};
```

styles.module.css

```
.test{
  background-color: green;
}
```

I have installed `npm install node-sass` no compile time error.

Comment: did you create the project using create-react-app? how did you add support for scss?

Comment: i used `ionic start` and then ran `npm install node-sass ` for scss support. After running this no compile issue but the styles are not picked up

Comment: did you change both the file name *and* the import from `styles.module.css` to `styles.module.scss`

Comment: yes. I changed at both places or i'm getting compiler error. The app is up i see class="test" in developer tools. but styles are missing